# Subset and remove rows from a dataset

Tags: r

I want to exclude some rows from my dataset while I also subset it. Something like I wrote below.

```
 a<-c(2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14)
 c<-c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4,4)
 d<-c(10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30, 50, 50, 50)
 ID<-rep(c("no","bo", "fo"), each=3)
 mydata<-data.frame(ID, a, c, d)
 gg.df <- melt(mydata, id="ID", variable.name="variable")
 gg.df[gg.df$variable=="a"& gg.df$ID==-"fo", ]
```

Comment: `gg.df$ID == -"fo"` should be `gg.df$ID != "fo"`.  Unary operators are not valid on character strings

Comment: how can this be done with:  `subset( x  = gg.df,  subset=variable == "a")`

Comment: Same deal, just stick the whole condition in `subset(gg.df, variable == "a" & ID != "fo")`

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. I was  just curious to know how subset approach would work